# Spring data flow skipper failed to start after deployment to CF

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have an issue that after pushing the applications, both scdf server and skipper, fails to start due to authentication error. This is related to the internal scdf user (deployer user) which stop/start that tasks/apps.

The user that set in the yml file is a space developer and org manager.
Is was created with cf command - ( cf create-user ).

Trying to login manually with this user succeed only with 
**"cf auth [user] [pwd] --origin uaa"**
However trying to login with 
**"cf login -u [user] -p [pwd] fails.**

How can I set scdf to authenticated it's deployment internal user with cf auth and not cf login as this is the authentication method seems to be applied?

Will appreciate any assistance here

When setting my organisation credentials the issue solved. This hints that skipper authentication implementation applied with "cf login -user" ... since this is how i login to cf.

However deploying skipper server with personal credentials is not allowed.

My skipper yaml configuration related to this issue are:

```
*JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'
SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_ORG: org1     SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_SKIP_SSL_VALIDATION: false
SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_SPACE: space1    SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_URL: <our cf api domain>    SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_USERNAME: admin-user
SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_PASSWORD: some-password
SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_DOMAIN: <domain>*
```

The error from skipper is: (User authentication failed)

```
ERROR .a.CloudFoundryPlatformAutoConfiguration : Cloud Foundry platform account [default] could not be registered: unauthorized: invalid_grant ;User authentication failed. Error creating bean with name 'deployerInitializationService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/skipper/server/config/SkipperServerPlatformConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'deployerInitializationService' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cloudFoundryPlatform' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/skipper/server/autoconfigure/CloudFoundryPlatformAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.skipper.domain.Platform]: Factory method 'cloudFoundryPlatform' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.skipper.SkipperException: unauthorized: {&quot;error&quot;:&quot;invalid_grant&quot;,&quot;error_description&quot;:&quot;User authentication failed.&quot;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is support non-default UAA, since spring cloud data flow skipper 2.2.0.RC1 and data flow server 2.3.0.RC1.
Issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

currently the relevant code of both spring data flow server and skipper is not supported to login with no-default uaa.
an issue created to spring data flow. (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry/issues/316)